# android studio how to import custom java class from other module(package)?

Tags: android

i'm trying to use opensource android project

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

so i cloned library module(there exist ObservableGridView, ...)

but i can't import that libraries... i don't know what is is and how to do. please help me.

but... i don't know how can i show my problem. i'm working in develop company so this code should not be shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) First of all keep library parallel with your android project

For eg: My library name is mylibs and it is located under D:\Android_Workspace

So My project must be located under D:\Android_Workspace and my android project's name is MyApp

But both will be parally  located

2) Ill recommend you to see this video => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk

It will explain  all steps clearly

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Go to File -> New Module, a new dialog 'Create New Model' will be opened
2. Select 'Import Gradle project'
3. Press Next button
4. Select source directory
5. Finish